# Jmeter - How to send query parameter which has :: in its value

Tags: api, url, jmeter, http-request-parameters

sample API call below ,

Http Method : **GET**

`https://sampledomain.com/api?bucket=abc&table=xyz&filters=uuid::12367d-ae0b-44b5-9813-zxzxzx6c00000,anotheruuid::324,date::2022-04-01|2022-04-06,uuid3::1BABFPDT`

Here in the API request, query parameter  **filters** is having comma(,) separated key::value pairs (**::**).

In postman the API call works fine but in Jmeter it errors out with 400 error.

We tried adding query params by directly giving it as path url and also by adding params value . enabled and disabled url encode.

In the request header we are seeing %3A in place of :.

Below is the sample request that is sent using jmeter.

`https://sampledomain.com/api?bucket=abc&table=xyz&filters=uuid%3A%3A12367d-ae0b-44b5-9813-zxzxzx6c00000%2Canotheruuid%3A%3A324%2Cdate%3A%3A2022-04-01%7C2022-04-06%2Cuuid3%3A%3A1BABFPDT`

How to send the query parameter values which contains **::** ?

Answer (score 1):

Tick "URL Encode" box for the `filters` parameter in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) and that would be it:

[image]

Going forward if you're uncertain regarding how to properly build this or that request you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response . 
I have already tried checking/ unchecking "URL Encode"  and is not making any difference. I am still seeing the URL sent with %3A.